# How can I compare performance between 100 groups?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I want to compare performance between 100 groups. Each group can be described by a value, say group size. In other words, I want to see how performance changes with group size.

Each group has multiple members. Each member can be a member of more than group. The unit of analysis is at the member level.

OLS fails because the error term is no longer independent because each member can be a part of multiple groups. Which regression should I use?

Comment: I don't think you have this issue if your covariates are the indicator variables for each member. In that case the error term should be independent of any covariate, and therefore not correlated via membership. Of course, you still need to do all of the other work to make sure OLS is appropriate for this dataset.

Comment: Make sure the groups are "real" and are not categorizations of underlying phenomena that should have been directly modeled.  If there are really groups and some are overlapping you can use a cluster sandwich covariance estimator to adjust for correlated data, perhaps.